# iOS 11.0.2 - AirDrop not showing up in Control Center even after long pressing the "Network Icon Group" in the Control Center

Tags: iphone, ios

Good day everyone, I have this iPhone unit which we updated to iOS 11.0.2. We were trying to AirDrop files to and from it, but we hit a snag when we were trying to go to the AirDrop control through the Control Center. It wasn't popping up even when we were long pressing the "Network Icon Group".

Does anyone know why this happens?

I know we can go to the Settings itself and search for AirDrop settings and turn it on, but it's so convenient to be able to turn it on and off from the Control Center.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am using an iPhone SE and a long press on the network settings box in the control center is working fine for me.

If the box opens but there is still no icon, you can check if there are any restrictions active like in the article mentioned by Melvin Jefferson (found in settings / general / restrictions).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some instructions on how to get access to air drop in your control center. https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/access-your-airdrop-settings-ios-11s-new-control-center-0180144/

Comment: There's no AirDrop icon there.

Comment: Actually I apologize, if you have your network settings already available in control center (wifi Bluetooth, etc) then 3d touch that box to open it up and air drop is right there. https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/access-your-airdrop-settings-ios-11s-new-control-center-0180144/

Comment: With the iPhone SE you cant 3D touch so its slightly different.

Comment: Oh, it might be an iPhone SE. :/ I did not factor that in.

Comment: Right. But check out the article above and see if that works. If not, then go to settings, your name, and scroll to the bottom until you see your devices (using the same Apple ID). The one that says "This iPhone _" is the name of your iPhone. If it is an iPhone SE, let me know.